# Disable extra row in listview wpf

Tags: wpf, listview

[image]

I have this `ListView` and at the end of the last item you can click to the right and type in a `TextBox`, like shown. How can I disable this?

Comment: One potential cause is when a `ListView` and `DataGrid` are both bound to the same collection and the `DataGrid` has `CanUserAddRows` set to `true` but without further explanation or code demonstrating the issue it is difficult to know how to best help you.

Comment: please, show your XAML

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prohibit writing in `TextBox` of your `DataTemplate` of `ListView`, then just set 'IsReadOnly' property of `TextBox` to `true`. Let me show an example:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Or just use `TextBlock` instead of `TextBox`. `TextBlock`, by default, does not give an opportunity to write inside this control:

```
<TextBlock Text="I am a TextBlock. You cannot change this text.:)"/>
```